# Responsive 2 column layout in Angular Material with mat-grid-list

Tags: angular, angular-material, responsive

I want to create an Angular Page with 2 columns and many rows. I was able to achieve it with `mat-grid-list`. The grid will have `mat-card` inside of it.

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <h1 class="mat-h1">Account</h1>
    <mat-grid-list cols=2>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-card class="account-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>
                        Address
                        <button mat-icon-button class="more-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Toggle menu">
                            <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
                            <button mat-menu-item>Expand</button>
                            <button mat-menu-item>Remove</button>
                        </mat-menu>
                    </mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                    <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                    <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput disabled placeholder="Placeholder" [value]='(claim$ | async)?.given_name'>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                    <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput disabled placeholder="Placeholder" [value]='(claim$ | async)?.family_name'>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-card class="account-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>
                        Subscription
                        <button mat-icon-button class="more-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Toggle menu">
                            <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
                            <button mat-menu-item>Expand</button>
                            <button mat-menu-item>Remove</button>
                        </mat-menu>
                    </mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                    <div>
                        <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                        <mat-label>Subscription Group</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput disabled placeholder="Placeholder" [value]=''>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

There are two issues with my code. The `mat-card` is displayed in the center of the two columns. Secondly it is not responsive when I change the browser size.

How can I:

1. Set the widths of the two columns to the size of the card (or 2 columns), and leave empty space after the second card so the cards are aligned to the left?
2. When the browser size changes, I want to stack the card from the second column to the bottom of the first one.

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Rather than using this mat-grid stuff, have you considered just using CSS grid? 
I think you can accomplish your goals using CSS grid and a media query to move change the number of columns based on the width of the screen.